# Performing a type of union of two IEnumerable collections

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, c#-4.0

Let's say you have two collections of integers:

```
IEnumerable<int> col1=new List<int> {2,3,3,5,7,11,11,11,13};
IEnumerable<int> col2=new List<int> {5,7,7,7,11,19};
```

Now I would like to create a third collection, `col3`, such that for every distinct element that appears in either `col1` or `col2`, `col3` will contain that element with at least as many occurances as the maximum number of occurrences of the element in either col1 or col2, but no more. Let me show the end result, then elaborate further:

```
   IEnumerable<int> col3=...;
```

The contents of col3 should be:

`{2,3,3,5,7,7,7,11,11,11,13,19}`

Another way to describe the contents of col3 as the result of this "pseudo-union" operation is that it should contain enough elements of each value, but no more, such that either of the two original collections could be formed individually (i.e., one at a time, from the entire domain of numbers in col3) by extracting elements from `col3`.

In case there is still confusion by what I mean when I say, "one at a time", imagine that `col1` and `col2` are instead collections of different types of marbles, with duplicates. I want to form `col3` such that I have the minimum amount of the different types of marbles, so that I can remove enough marbles from `col3` to form `col1`, then put the marbles back into `col3`, then remove enough marbles to form `col2`.

I would love it if the answer used LINQ to come up with a single expression that solves the problem, because the two methods I've thought of so far involve:

1. Merging dictionaries which contain histograms (i.e., number of occurences of each different integer).
2. Constructing a dictionary from `col1` and then doing a "mark and insert" type operation while processing `col2`, resulting in a final dictionary with just enough count for each integer to satisfy my criteria.

Update: The input collections are guaranteed to be sorted (i.e., monotonic and non-decreasing) and the resulting collection should be in the same order.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like this:

```
var groups1 = col1.ToLookup(e => e);
var groups2 = col2.ToLookup(e => e);

var col3 = col1.Union(col2)
               .SelectMany(e => Enumerable.Repeat(e, 
                   Math.Max(
                            groups1[e].Count(), 
                            groups2[e].Count()
                   )
                ));
```

Comment: It seems to solve the problem. I wonder if there's any way to do this without the two groups intermediate vars.

Comment: @Michael: Not without writing a loop.  (perhaps in a custom extension method)

Comment: Well I suppose you could replace groups1/groups2 with their formation code (i.e., col1.ToLookup(e => e)), but this would be inefficient since they would be recreated at each iteration of SelectMany

Comment: @Michael: You could write `col1.Count(c => c == e)`, which would be slightly less inefficient.

Comment: Yes, but it would also amount to a linear search in each collection for each count vs. hopefully a logarithmic (or constant time, if they're hashes) lookup in the groups1 dictionaries.

Comment: I realize that.  That's why I said _slightly_.

Comment: ... and I meant lookups, not dictionaries in my comment ;)